# Shipping 1.2 million records with an iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a data set of 1.2 million key-value pairs. The keys are a string (a sequence of numbers up to 22 characters in length), and the values are strings.

What's the best way to ship this so a value can be looked up and retrieved quickly?

I suspect a plist is not the way to go for a data set this size.

I have the data set stored in two ways - a CSV, and a mySQL database table with 2 columns. I
ll go forward using whatever method gets the data into the app the best.

Comment: http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/

Comment: One method I've used in the past was to prepare the dataset by converting it to binary and then reading (decoding) it back into the app from an external file at launch. (the dataset was 1.5m records with around a dozen components each) It was pretty quick, that's all I can say really. (you can probably find a good Obj-C binary encoder/decoder on the web)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a collection of text files could work well. you can:

- divide them into multiple files (e.g. by leading character range).
- order pairs appropriately (e.g. by character number)
- and quickly/easily read incrementally/portions as appropriate.
- balance resources between file reads and memory usage well.
- choosing the right encoding for the strings can also help (i'd start with utf8 if it's mostly in ascii).

if distribution size is also your concern, you could compress/decompress these files.

or you can just take this approach and use a custom serialized class to represent a subsets of the collection if that sounds like too much parse and read implementation.

if you're using objc types for storage and/or parsing, then it would be good to keep those files small. if you use c or c++, then it would help to profile the app.

your data set will require up to 30 MB using an 8 bit per character single byte encoding. one large file  (again, ordered) which you mmap would also be worth consideration. see `[NSData initWithContentsOfMappedFile:path];`.

Answer (score 3):

Core Data and SQLite are two good options for dealing with very large data sets in iOS. It's not difficult to create a Core Data model for the kind of data you're talking about. You can then copy that model into a little command line program that you'll write to move the data into a Core Data store. You can then move the resulting data file into your iOS app's resources.

A third option, particularly useful if the data is likely to change often, is to build a web service to provide the data from the service. I don't think this is what you're asking about, but it's something to consider if the data set is very large and/or subject to frequent change.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience is with a plist file that has only thousands of records and I can say that it isn't it so fast. So my options for this amount of data you have are:

- A database.
- Or if you have a sorting criteria for those keys and prefer plist
  files split it in many files and keep a reference dictionary with the start key of every file. For ex. all keys that begin with 'abc' go in a.plist etc.

(I don't know if it's the case with your app but you can consider moving the data to a server and search via a webservice, specifically if your data will grow.)

Answer (score 0):

A sqlite file is probably your best bet. You can create it on the desktop using either the command-line sqlite3 or any sqlite gui. Make sure you index the key column.

Import the csv file as described here: [Importing csv files into sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles)

Then just add the database to your project/target. If you want to modify the database at runtime, however, you'll have to copy it out into your Documents or cache directories.

For an objective-c wrapper around sqlite, I like [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)